When updating Angular app from v9 to v10, it asks for minimum Node.js version of v18.13
I am currently working on updating my Angular project from v9 to v10.
My Angular CLI version is 9.1.15 and Node.js version is 12.18.1.

Following the Angular Update Guide, I attempted to execute the command npx @angular/cli@10 update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10. But it gives me below error:

This error message is confusing to me because my current Node.js version (v12.18.1) exceeds the minimum requirement stated in the Angular Update Guide(which is v12 or later).
Can someone clarify why this error is occurring and provide guidance on how to proceed with updating my Angular project? Thanks.

open your command line prompt and run ng -v to check what version of angular cli is configured globally? please update on the question. Also you need to run this command on the same folder as the package.json of your project

@NarenMurali I ran the command and it gives me same CLI version 9.1.15 and Node.js version 12.18.1

sorry, but please run the command prompt on C:// drive instead of on the project, so that the global version comes!

Yes globally also CLI version is 9.1.15

Version 18.13 of node is the current version required by Angular 17, which makes me believe there mght be another installation of @angular/cli
